# General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db_name.catalog_category_flat_store_1'

Tags: database, reindex, indexer

I am trying to reindex Category Flat Data via ssh with the command `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat` but I am getting error as below. I have tried all the solutions posted on the forum but I am not able to fix the issue. Can you look into the error log and let me know if there is any way to fix the issue?

```
[cpanelusername@server shell]$ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
Category Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'cpanelusername_magento.catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: -1)' in /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#6 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#7 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#8 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1418): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#9 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1431): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#10 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#12 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/cpanelusername/public_html/catalog/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
```

I dont have any DB table called `cpanelusername_magento.catalog_category_flat_store_1`

Comment: What have you tried exactly? See the first error in [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html).

Comment: Thanks. If a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed how can I fix it. I have already tried repairing the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was something else not posted anywhere. I solved the issue by exporting the database and importing it to new database name.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the solution.

Tables catalog_category_entity and core_store were MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

Check these two tables in your database and if they are MyISAM instead of InnoDB, run these SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE core_store ENGINE=INNODB;
```